# forwarding http request

Tags: apache, web-applications, dns, glassfish

i hope to find out a solution to my issue.

Here's my scenario:
i have developed a web application using glassfish, my application actually work on `http://localhost:8080/myapp`.
I also bought a domain and associated with my public ip address. Note that my application is located on a virtual host (with another ip adresss), so i need to forward the request from the public ip address to the virtual host IP address . How can i do that? 
After the request has been forwarded to the correct IP address,  i want to launch my application by using the domain name and not the ip adress, so i want to do something like this `http://www.mydomain.it` for start my app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make available the application to a public IP address (i believe you got that right using the virtual host).

Then you have to redirect the trafic from your domain to that public ip address where the application is available. This can be done in different ways depending on your domain provider. Some providers have a web interface to do this redirection, and some others not. Look what is available from the side of your domain provider

Comment: thk for answer me... how i can make available the application to a public IP address (using virtual host)??...i havnt do that